# dynamic scheduled task

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a console application to run daily at a certain time of the day. I have used "Scheduled Tasks" feature of Windows.

Is there a way to dynamically change the time-of-the-day programmatically by C# for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API available but as far as I know not for managed code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384006(VS.85).aspx

Alternatively you could let your program use the command line interface (schtasks).